# Solutions to a parametrized optimization problem

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-programming

I have the following maximization program

\begin{align}
    \max\limits_{\{q_i\}}&\quad\sum\limits_{i=1}^nq_i \\
    \text{s.t.}&\quad\begin{cases} k_j \geq \sum\limits_{i=1}^n q_i^{1 \over \alpha}x_{ij} & j=\{1,\dots,J\} \\
     q_i \geq 0 & i=\{1,\dots,n\} \\
    \end{cases} \end{align}

with $\alpha>0$, $x_{ij}\geq 0$ and $k_j \geq 0$ for all indices. I'd like to prove that if $\mathbf q^*=(q_1^*,\dots,q_n^*)$ is a solution to this problem for  $\mathbf k^*=(k_1^*,\dots,k_J^*),$ then $\delta^{\alpha}\mathbf q^*$ is a solution for $\delta \mathbf k^*.$

I proceed by contradiction:

Assume that the solution for $\delta \mathbf k^*$ was $\mathbf {\hat q}$ and such that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \hat q_i>\delta^{\alpha}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n q_i^*$. Consider $\mathbf {\bar q}=\dfrac1{\delta^{\alpha}}\mathbf {\hat q}.$ It is easily seen that $\mathbf {\bar q}$ is feasible for $\mathbf k^*$. But we have that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \bar q_i>\sum_{i=1}^n q_i^*,$$

so $\mathbf q^*$ cannot be a solution for $\mathbf k^*$.

Is this correct? I worry that if the program has multiple solutions (and this can be the case when $\alpha>1$) my proof is not general enough or even wrong altogether.

**Edit:** Perhaps it would be more accurate to say that, letting $\mathbf S(\mathbf k) $ denote the set of solutions to the maximization program for a given $\mathbf k$, $$\mathbf q^*\in \mathbf S(\mathbf k^*) \iff \delta^{\alpha}\mathbf q^*\in \mathbf S(\delta\mathbf k^*)$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your logic seems fine to me. There's no issue with multiple solutions: just make $\hat{\bf{q}}$ *any* optimal solution to the modified problem.